# Installing Git-TFS without Git itself

Tags: git, windows-7, git-tfs, chocolatey

Currently, the only way to install the Git-TFS bridge is [through Chocolatey](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs#installing). When I tried it, however, it appears to install Git (for Windows) along with the actual Git-TFS package. I already have Git installed on my work machine, so I don't need it to modify/remove what's already there.

Is there a way to force Chocolatey not to modify my current Git install and just put in the Git-TFS package? If there is, how do I configure it to use with my current Git install?

Comment: It sounds like we need a switch for ignore dependencies... https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/issues/131

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak for other git clients, but if you're using the git-bash shell, you can download the source for git-tfs from github, compile it,  and put it anywhere on your system and add that location to your path environment variable.  The shell will find git-tfs and hook it in.

Comment: I just downloaded the Git-TFS files and put its location in my $PATH. It worked! (Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but this allows me to do away with Chocolatey.)

Comment: Download link for v0.20.0 https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/releases/download/v0.20.0/GitTfs-0.20.0.zip from http://git-tfs.com/ (latest at time of writing)

Comment: Using bash specifically is what I had to do...the docs say to use a command prompt, but the windows cmd.exe didn't work - had to use bash.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to let the bridge install Git, while keeping your Git installation in a custom directory, which you can easily do with the [Portable application for official Git for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) (ie a seup you can simply uncompress anywhere you like).

From there, using your git installation is mainly about catching your global config settings, which are in `%HOME%/.gitconfig`. So make sure you have `HOME` defined, and bot git (yours and the one installed by the bridge) will use those.

---

Now if you don't need a portable installation (or a full recompilation like [edwinf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440011/edwinf) suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10916204/6309)), then [ferventcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18475/ferventcoder) (member of the [chocolatey organization](https://github.com/chocolatey)) suggests in the comment to look at/comment on [issue 131](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/issues/131):

> Add a switch for ignoring dependencies on install (Something like `-ignoredependencies`)

Comment: I guess that means a "no." :) If there's a way to use the [Git-TFS files from Github](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/downloads) directly with Git (after unzipping them somewhere), that would be a better workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @Isxek true, but I didn't find the need for one git to use another, except for the global settings. So I usually leave the different Git installations alone.

Comment: Adding a switch to ignore dependencies will probably work best... https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/issues/131

Comment: @ferventcoder True. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could [download git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/releases).

No need to use chocolatey! (But chocolatey is a very good tool ;))

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to an option which will only work until 11-feb-2013 - see https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads

Comment: It's gone from the github UI *but* the link at the top of http://git-tfs.com/ still works, which is pointing here -> https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/releases/download/v0.20.0/GitTfs-0.20.0.zip (v0.20.0, latest at time of writing) Hurrah.

Comment: Yes. "Upload" has been deprecated by GitHub just to be replaced by "Release". We know use that to release git-tfs binaries...(see my link in my answer). And Chocolatey is just a wrapper toward this zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Just download and extract the latest build, and put that directory in your PATH.